# How to delete last sendded message from bot. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Hi, I'm new here and I've tried to delete last sendded message by bot but I cant do it can u help me with this problem**

I've tried this (but it doesn't work):

```
if (msg.author.bot) msg.delete()
```

and also this:

```
setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
```

my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "resetuj",
    description: "Resetuje konto gracza!",
  
    async run(client, message) { 
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/);
        const Nadano = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Nie posiadasz permisji do tej komendy!")
        .setColor(0x0EC0E7)
        .setTimestamp('')
        .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/814587842071101530/2b018bbe88c48b277a50145a404cdaea.png?size=512')
        .setDescription("**Komenda dla administracji! #｜- **")
        message.channel.send(Nadano);
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
}
```

Comment: Which version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: @Phoenix discord.js v13

Comment: When you say you've tried those methods, can you add other relevant code from where they were used? Just these single lines alone won't be able to help much!

Comment: @Phoenix yea ill add in few secs then in post

Comment: @Phoenix yo i added it bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Message.author.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/User?scrollTo=id) returns a snowflake that doesn't have the `.delete()` method. You'll want to resolve the promise that [`message.channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) returns and call `setTimeout` inside of that callback function so you have access to the newly sent message object:

```
message.channel.send(Nadano)
.then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000)
})
```

Or as pointed out below, you can use `await` instead if you're in an `async` function:

```
const msg = await message.channel.send(Nadano);
setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000);
```

Comment: Or await syntax since you've marked the function as async already:

`msg = await message.channel.send(Nadano)` and

`setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000)`